# Weird black egg-like things on cherry fruit tree leaves

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, leaves, bugs, cherries

My bing cherry fruit tree just developed this about a week or so.

It is mostly near the top of the branches on small leaves:

[image]

Here is another shot (shiny thing was Neem Oil I tried to put on but didn't do any good):

[image]

Any idea what happened here and how to fix it?

It is May in Pacific Northwest now.

Comment: That looks like aphids, search google or this website for solutions against this pest.

Answer (score 1):

Cherry blackfly/aphid; as this is a fruiting cherry, be careful which insecticide you choose to  use, pick one that will do the trick but is suitable for use on food plants, otherwise the fruits will contain insecticide. It's only feasible  to spray if it's possible to reach all parts of the tree, and once leaves have curled over, treatment is not terribly effective. Further information here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=488 but any proprietary treatments mentioned apply to the UK - if you're in the States, you likely have more insecticides available to you.

Comment: we do love our poison... pyrethrum (still considered organic in the USA) or pyrethrum + Piperonyl butoxide  (not organic, but probably more effective) are commonly sold for house and food plant sprays.

Dont spray from the time the flowers buds are visible until after the petal have dropped, you dont want to kill bees.